# p:dataTable with scrollable and one frozen column but scroll not coming

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable

there is a `p:dataTable` with `scrollable="true`" `frozenColumns="1"` in `h:panelGroup`, and on page load the panelGroup has `display:none`. On clicking a button the property is changed to `display:block`. But the scroll does not appear now. But if i keep `display:block` on page load, things work fine.

Comment: Please state your PF Version?

Comment: I think it is caused by dynamically determining the size based on the size of a parent. A hidden div (panelgroup) has a width of 0. Can you give it, or the datatable, an explicit with and see what happens then?

Comment: @Kukeltje I have already tried that. it's not working. i am using PF 5.3 version.

Comment: Then please create an [mcve]

Comment: Thanks, i incorporated the solution wisely. it worked. :) @Kukeltje

Comment: Stil please create an mcve in the question AND postthe solution as an answer